# Angular 6 Create an observable to check a variable for change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am using Angular 6 and I want to check a variable for changes and the stop or unsubscribe when the variable has a value.

So I was thinking of an Observable:

```
myValue; // variable to be checked

myObservable = Observable.timer(2000); // every 2 seconds

myObservable.subscribe(); // start
```

Then keep checking myValue and if the value is not empty

```
myObservable.unsubscribe(); // stop
```

This is the idea anyway...

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can pretty much guarantee that there's a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: I completely agree with @IngoBürk, this sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is that I'm making a few api calls and I need to make sure I have all the data before I can continue

Comment: Then you should use appropriate rxjs pipelines and operators for that. But you need to show more code for us to help you with that. Things to look at would be, eg, forkJoin.

Comment: Have a look at [Requests with concatMap() vs mergeMap() vs forkJoin()](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do something when the value is being set, you can use a getter and setter instead of an observable:

```
private _value: any;
public set value(value: any) {
  this._value = value;
  window.alert("Value is set!");
}
public get value() { return this._value; }
```

Depending on the actual underlying problem there might be other (better) solutions as well.

Comment: Do I need to put this on a setTimeout in order to it to keep checking that the variable is not empty?

Comment: No, you don't need that. The setter is invoked every time someone tries to assign a value to it.